# MERGE INTO Performance as table grows

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-merge, full-table-scan

This is a general question about the Oracle `MERGE INTO` statement with a particular scenario, on Oracle RDBMS 12c.

Daily data will be loaded to `StagingTableA` - about 10m rows.
This will be `MERGEd INTO TableA`.
`TableA` will vary between 0 to 10m rows (matcing `StagingTableA`).
There may be times when `TableA` will be pruned/emptied and left with 0 rows.

Clearly, when `TableA` is empty, a straight `INSERT` will do the job, but the procedure has been written to use a `MERGE INTO` method to handle all scenarios.

The `MERGE .. MATCH` is on a indexed column.

My question is an uncertainty about how the `MERGE` handles the `MATCH` in circumstances where `TableA` will start empty, and then grow hugely during the `MERGE` execution. The `MATCH` on indexed columns will use a FTS as the stats will show the table has 0 rows.

At some point during the `MERGE` transaction, this will become inefficient.

Is the `MERGE` statement clever enough to detect this and change the execution plan, and start using the index instead of the FTS?

If this was done the old way with `CURSOR`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT` then we could potentially introduce a `ANALYZE` at a appropriate point (say after 50,000 processed) on the `TableA` to switch to a optimal plan.

I haven't been able to find any documentation dealing with this specific question.

Comment: If this was SQL Server I'd say bad idea due to `MERGE` in general being bad, and cached parameter plans. Oracle I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've got a UNIQUE index on that table, which is based on the incoming data. If I was you, rather than using a simple MERGE I'd:

1. Mark all indexes on the table as UNUSABLE, *except* for the unique index.
2. INSERT all records
3. Catch the `DUPLICATE VALUE ON INDEX` exception at the time of INSERT and issue the appropriate UPDATE.
4. DELETE processed rows from the input record.
5. Commit every N records (1000? 10000? 100000? Your choice...), calling `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` for the table you've inserted into after each COMMIT.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Bob, all makes sense, but the question was about trying to understand whether or not MERGE has this stats handling built-in or not. To be fair, no one seems to know, and the indication of some cursory tests I've done indicate it's might not be as smart as I hope it would be.

Comment: As far as I'm aware Oracle does not gather stats during DML operations of any sort.